# Do scripts 'block' when executed from rcS?

Tags: linux, init, busybox

I'm using Busybox (ash), which at startup runs rcS, which in turn executes, in numerical order, all the S?? scripts in /etc/init.d

Does this script wait for completion before execution the next? Or will it 'asynchronously' run everything in parallel, simply starting execution at the lowest number?

Thinking about it, wouldn't it make sense to execute numerically, running only scripts with the same number in parallel, but the rest of them in series? I'm fairly sure rcS is not that 'fancy'. Is there a relatively 'light way' to do this?

I'm on an embedded system where boot time is a key factor (so, I don't like the idea to migrate to a more advanced, but slower, System-D).

Comment: The answer is right there in the rcS script. Each S* file is executed sequentially, one after the other. There is no concurrency. If you still have doubts, then insert some echo commands (in the various scripts) to tell you what is happening.  BTW your title makes no sense.

Comment: Thx. I'll run some tests. Regarding the title, it's 'blocking' as in opposite to 'asynchronous'.